# Why is the "2 minute tour" comment a bad comment?

Tags: support, status-completed

In the lifehacks [2 minute tour](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tour), there is a comment section near the bottom.

However, I have noticed that the comment is a +1 comment.

> This is great and easy to do. +1

[image]

We are not to use comments for this. They are for suggesting edits.

My feature request is, for a moderater to change the answer so that a diffrent comment will show up.

Comment: Well spotted! But, I don't know how much of an issue it is, at this point.....I mean, right now we're in private beta, so anyone seeing these things should now what they're about. Later, when we're in public beta, I'm pretty sure that we'll get the chance to *choose* which question gets put up there for the tour.

Comment: I picked another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***I sort of agree that the comment in the "2 Minute Tour" may be subject to misunderstanding and should probably be changed because of that. But is it a really big deal and could it be considered fine? Well, yes it could. My reasoning:***

The comment said "This is great and easy to do. +1 - michaelpri Dec 16 at 2:43"

The "[2 Minute Tour](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tour)" said:

> Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or
>   answer.

That comment is in a way giving that answer validity. And if that is the Questioner, that user is telling other users that this method will work fine for their problem.

I, however, think that it should be replaced, due to adding confusion. On the site it says [avoid 1+ and Thank You phrases](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), this rule can be observed here:

> **Compliments** which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and pay it forward;
>
> **Criticisms** which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous comments you scallywag!"); instead, down-vote (and provide or
>   up-vote a better answer if appropriate);

**The original Question:**

[How to seal envelopes without licking](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1862/how-to-seal-envelopes-without-licking)

Comment: I agree with this answer. See my similar answer, [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2293/5323).